# Why does adding a variable as a property to an object in a loop add the actual name of the variable as the property the first time around?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

I'm trying to add a string stored by the variable venueID to an object called "stop." The stop objects are stored in an object called venues. For some reason, if a particular stop does not yet exist in the venues object, when I add the stop to the venues object and set it equal to another object with the property venueID, the venueID gets added as the string "venueID" instead of the value stored in the variable venueID. Why is this?

```
var getMostPopularVenues = function(checkins) {
    var venues = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < checkins.length; i++) {
        var checkin = checkins[i];
        var venue = {'venueName' : checkin['venueName'], 'count' : 1};
        var stop = checkin['stop'];
        var venueID = checkin['venueID'];
        if (stop in venues) {
            if (venueID in venues[stop]) {
                venues[stop][venueID]['count']++;
            }
            else {
                venues[stop][venueID] = venue; 
            }
        }
        else {
            console.log(venueID); // correctly prints the actual venueID that I want to set as the property
            venues[stop] = {venueID : venue}; // this line gives the stop a property called the string 'venueID' instead of the value stored by the variable venueID
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object literal `{venueID : venue}` is the *same* as `{"venueID" : venue}`.

An object literal *cannot* be used to set a dynamic property name and this must be done in two parts.

For instance,

```
venues[stop] = {};
venues[stop][venueID] = venue;
```